# Bar position on the x-axis

Tags: javascript

How to set the place where the bar is displayed on the X axis: first position, second position, etc., not using "," (data: [,,,,11504])? The echarts library was used, the code is fully functional. Please help me how to write it. How to optimally shorten the code. Thanks in advance! The code comes from the echarts site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%">
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
   <body style="height: 100%; margin: 0">
       <div id="container" style="height: 100%"></div>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://echarts.baidu.com/gallery/vendors/echarts/echarts.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
var dom = document.getElementById("container");
            var myChart = echarts.init(dom);
            var app = {};
            option = null;

            app.title = '';

            option = {
                legend: {
                    data: ['Audi 1/2017', 'Audi 2/2017', 'Audi 1/2018','VW 1/2017','VW 1/2018','Volvo 1/2017','Volvo 1/2017','Lam 1/2017','Lam 2/2017','Lam 1/2018','Lam 2/2018','Lam 3/2018'],
                    orient: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    top: 20,
                    right: 10
                },
                xAxis: [{
                    type: 'category',
                    position: "bottom",
                    data: ['2017','2018','2017','2018','2017','2018','2017','2018']
                }],
                yAxis: {
                    type: 'value',
                    boundaryGap: [0, 0.01]
                },
                series: [
                    {
                        name: 'Audi 1/2017',
                        type: 'bar',
                        stack: '2017',
                        barWidth:'70%',
                        barGap: '-100%',
                        data: [11203]
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Audi 2/2017',
                        type: 'bar',
                        stack: '2017',
                        barWidth:'70%',
                        barGap: '-100%',
                        data: [12325]
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Audi 1/2018',
                        type: 'bar',
                        stack: '2018',            
                        barWidth:'70%',
                        barGap: '-100%',
                        data: [,12594]
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Lam 1/2017',
                        type: 'bar',
                        stack: 'UK2017',            
                        barWidth:'70%',
                        barGap: '-100%',
                        data: [,,,,11504]
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Lam 2/2017',
                        type: 'bar',
                        stack: 'UK2017',
                        barWidth:'70%',
                        barGap: '-100%',
                        data: [,,,,11203]
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Lam 1/2018',
                        type: 'bar',
                        stack: 'UK2018',            
                        barWidth:'70%',
                        barGap: '-100%',
                        data: [,,,,,11594]
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Lam 2/2018',
                        type: 'bar',
                        stack: 'UK2018',            
                        barWidth:'70%',
                        barGap: '-100%',
                        data: [,,,,,15094]
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Lam 3/2018',
                        type: 'bar',
                        stack: 'UK2018',            
                        barWidth:'70%',
                        barGap: '-100%',
                        data: [,,,,,21594]
                    }
                ]
            };
            ;
            if (option && typeof option === "object") {
                myChart.setOption(option, true);
            }
        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array(length).fill(value, startIndex)`.

To create `[,,,,,21594]` you write:

```
Array(6).fill(21594, 5)
```

You can also use `Array(length).fill(value, startIndex, endIndexExclusive)` like so:

```
Array(6).fill(21594, 2, 3)
```

Which will return `[empty × 2, 21594, empty × 3]`.

You can create a function for this:

```
function getArray(index, value) {
    return Array(index + 1).fill(value, index);
}
```